# Google maps API not working with AJAX on Bitrix

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps, bitrix

I'm trying to use Google API and everything was fine except when I tried to use it with AJAX. So, let me explain my trouble. I'm using CMS Bitrix, and I have a task to use Google maps and of course they must be downloaded with AJAX. So when user enter my site and click the button to show maps, everything is OK. But when he enter the second page of offers(that is downloaded with AJAX), Google Maps show nothing. And I cannot understand why? Here are my scripts with PHP code. I hope you will help me =)

```
var map, infoWindow;

//Add marker to the map, with additional info
function addMarker(myLatlng, street, side) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            var contentString = "<h3>" + street + "</h3><i>" + side + "</i>";
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
};

//Initialization of the map
function initMap(result) {
    var arr = result[0]['coord'].split(',');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 18,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    //touch the map to close the info
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
            infoWindow.close();
    });

    //if we want just to see single marker on the map
    if(result.length == 1) {
        arr = result[0]['coord'].split(',');
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);

        addMarker(myLatlng, result[0]['street'], result[0]['side']);
    } else {
        //Many markers on the map
        var markersBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            arr = result[i]['coord'].split(',');
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);

            //for centralizing map
            markersBounds.extend(myLatlng);
            addMarker(myLatlng, result[i]['street'], result[i]['side']);
        }
        //set center of the map
        map.setCenter(markersBounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(markersBounds));
    }

    setTimeout(function() {google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");}, 600);
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    //Removing additional effects of fancybox
    $(".maphref").fancybox({
        touch: false
    });

    $(".allMarkers").fancybox({
        touch: false
    });


    //all citylights on the map
    $(".allMarkers").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: "/citylights/getAllCoord.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                initMap(result);
            }
        });
    });

    //single citylight on the map
    $(".maphref").bind("click", function() {
        var data = {'street': $(this).attr("data-street"), 'side': $(this).attr("data-side"), 'coord': $(this).attr("id")};
        var result = [data];
        initMap(result);
    });
});
```

In my head block I'm just including this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXFNLY_Nozy_x9nRw4QRBPMNzHY2Pzepc&sensor=false"></script>
```

And here is my PHP code on CMS Bitrix

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */

$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<a href="/citylights.xlsx">Download all citylights in .xlsx</a><br>
<a href="javascript:" class="allMarkers" data-fancybox data-src="#map">All citylights on a map</a>
<div class="clb"></div>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
    <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
<?endif;?>
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <div class="citylight" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
        <?if($street = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_STREET"]):?>
            <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                <a href="<?echo $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><b><?=$street["VALUE"]?></b></a><br />
            <?endif;?>
        <?endif;?>

        <?if($side = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_SIDE"]):?>
            <span id="side"><?=$side["VALUE"]?></span><br>
        <?endif?>
        <?if($city = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_CITY"]):?>
            <i id="city"><?=$city["VALUE"]?></i><br><br>
        <?endif?>

        <a href="javascript:" class="maphref" data-fancybox data-src="#map" data-side="<?=$arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_SIDE"]["VALUE"]?>" data-street="<?=$arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_STREET"]["VALUE"]?>" id="<?=$arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_MAP"]["VALUE"]?>" name="<?=$arItem["NAME"]?>">Show n map</a><br><br>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
            <?if(!$arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"] || ($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"] && $arResult["USER_HAVE_ACCESS"])):?>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"><img id="preview"
                        src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                        height="166"
                        width="200"
                        alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/></a>
            <?else:?>
                <img id="preview" src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"  width="200" alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"/>
            <?endif;?>
        <?endif?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <?endif?>
        <?if($date = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_DATE"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]):?>
            <div class="reserved"><p class="if"><span class="busy"></span><?=$arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_STATUS"]["DISPLAY_VALUE"]?></p>
            <i class="to">до <?=$date?></i></div><br>
        <?else:?>
            <a href="javascript:" data-name="<?=$arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_STREET"]["VALUE"]?>" data-ref="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" class="buy" id="<?=$arItem['ID']?>" data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-form">Buy</a><br>
        <?endif?>
        <?if($adv = $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["ATT_ADVANTAGE"]):?>
            <b><?=$adv["NAME"]?></b><br>
            <p class="advantage">
                <?foreach($adv["VALUE"] as $value):
                echo ($value.", ");
                endforeach?>
            </p>
        <?endif?>
    </div>
<?endforeach;?>
<div class="clb"></div>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
    <br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
<?endif;?>

<!-- Offers form -->
<form class="form-2" method="POST" action="" id="hidden-form">
    <div class="dop-info">
        <div class="dop-info-photo">
            <a href=""><img src="" width="100"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dop-info-info">
            <h4></h4>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="notice"></span><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your e-mail" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your telephone" name="telephone" id="telephone"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Your text" name="text" id="text"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="send">
    <input type="button" value="Close" class="close">
    <input type="hidden" name="city_id" value="<?=$arResult["ID"]?>" id="city_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="city_name" value="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" id="city_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="city_ref" value="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" id="city_ref">
</form>

<!-- Here would be our maps  -->
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual, answer was really simple. So, the problem was in my script and I needed to add $(document).ajaxComplete(....). So, now my script looks like this:

```
var map, infoWindow;

//Add marker to the map, with additional info
function addMarker(myLatlng, street, side) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            var contentString = "<h3>" + street + "</h3><i>" + side + "</i>";
            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
};

//Initialization of the map
function initMap(result) {
    var arr = result[0]['coord'].split(',');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 18,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    //touch the map to close the info
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
            infoWindow.close();
    });

    //if we want just to see single marker on the map
    if(result.length == 1) {
        arr = result[0]['coord'].split(',');
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);

        addMarker(myLatlng, result[0]['street'], result[0]['side']);
    } else {
        //Many markers on the map
        var markersBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            arr = result[i]['coord'].split(',');
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[0], arr[1]);

            //for centralizing map
            markersBounds.extend(myLatlng);
            addMarker(myLatlng, result[i]['street'], result[i]['side']);
        }
        //set center of the map
        map.setCenter(markersBounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(markersBounds));
    }

    setTimeout(function() {google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");}, 600);
};

function onLoadFunction() {
    //Removing additional effects of fancybox
    $(".maphref").fancybox({
        touch: false
    });

    $(".allMarkers").fancybox({
        touch: false
    });


    //all citylights on the map
    $(".allMarkers").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: "/citylights/getAllCoord.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                initMap(result);
            }
        });
    });

    //single citylight on the map
    $(".maphref").bind("click", function() {
        var data = {'street': $(this).attr("data-street"), 'side': $(this).attr("data-side"), 'coord': $(this).attr("id")};
        var result = [data];
        initMap(result);
    });
};


$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    onLoadFunction();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    onLoadFunction();
});
```